# Autosys/autorep list of downstream dependencies for a job

Tags: autosys

I am looking for a way to get a recursive list of downstream dependencies of a job in Autosys.

E.g. if **jobX1** has a condition of `s(jobA)` and **jobX2** has the same condition `s(jobA)`, I would like to be able to list that the downstream dependencies of **jobA** are **jobX1** and **jobX2** and their recursive downstream dependecies.

I need it because if I put **jobA** on ice but still need the downstream dependecies run, I want to get a quick list for forced executions.  I was hoping `autorep` would have an option but I don't seem to find one.

I know that I can write a Perl script that recurses dependecies and it'd be easy to do but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Did you get solution to your problem? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

use job_depends command. it has -c and -d options to list jobs before and after the job.

Answer (score 0):

On an Oracle-based 4.5 version of AutoSys (where 'autosys' is the schema), I have used the following query to get a list of recursive dependencies:

```
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(b.job_name,' ==> '),' ==> ') parent_child_grandchild
from autosys.job b
start with (   b.condition LIKE ('%jobA%')
         )             
and b.JOB_TYPE ='b'
connect by b.condition like PRIOR concat(concat('%',b.job_name),'%')
order by parent_child_grandchild;
```

Comment: thanks, however, i do not have access to the backend DB -- must interface through autorep